# Gitorious - ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod when logging in?

Tags: linux, centos, ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I'm going to install [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) as a slave server for failover purpose follow [this](http://famousphil.com/blog/2011/06/installing-gitorious-on-centos-5-6-x64/) blog post.

**`gitorious.conf`**

```
NameVirtualHost *:81

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName  gitorious.domain.com
    ServerAdmin quanta@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/git/gitorious/public
    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/gitorious_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/gitorious_access.log combined
    <Directory /home/git/gitorious/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
        Satisfy Any
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-git.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca-git.key
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    ServerName  gitorious.domain.com
    ServerAdmin quanta@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/git/gitorious/public
    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/gitorious_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/gitorious_access.log combined
    <Directory /home/git/gitorious/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
        Satisfy Any
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works fine until I try to login, Firefox give me the below errors:

```
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

**`production.log`**

```
ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod (V^C^A, accepted HTTP methods are get, head, put, post, delete, and options):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/request.rb:35:in `request_method_without_openid'
  vendor/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication/request.rb:11:in `request_method'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/request.rb:43:in `method'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:499:in `extract_request_environment_without_host'
  vendor/plugins/routing-filter/lib/routing_filter.rb:74:in `extract_request_environment'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:442:in `recognize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:437:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.17/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.17/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.17/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.17/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.17/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.17/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.17/lib/rails/rack/metal.rb:47:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.17/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:25:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.17/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:321:in `start_request_handler'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `send'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:270:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

**`gitorious_access.log`**

```
[22/Feb/2013:15:42:01 +0700] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 103 "http://gitorious.domain.com:81/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0"
 - - [22/Feb/2013:15:42:01 +0700] "\x16\x03\x01" 500 1921 "-" "-"
```

What does `\x16\x03\x01` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does `\x16\x03\x01` mean?

It is an weird URI.

If you pay attention to the address bar, you will see the URL is:

```
https://gitorious.domain.com:81/login
```

It means that you're trying to talk HTTPS to a HTTP server. The fix is simply remove the port number from that URL (`https://gitorious.domain.com/login`).